# Calculating second order degree of graph using Networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

Given a vertex v of a graph G the second order degree of v denoted as d 2(v) is defined as the number of vertices at distance 2 from v.

My question is the following - how (and is it) actully possible to calculate it using some built-in function in networkx or you need to use some other approach? After checking documentation did not find anything close to that.

Comment: Use breadth first search limited to a depth of 2.

Comment: @ravenspoint can you please elaborate more on your answer?

Comment: Do you know how to code a breadth first search?  Or, depth first since you could use either for this problem.  There are actually a number of different ways of doing this.  You could use Dijkstra and prune all paths that are less than 2 hops.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some C++ code to solve this problem using a depth first search.  I assume you can port this to python, though you will loose significant performance

```
       int cPathFinder::countCloseNodes(
            int v,              // start node
            int maxdepth)       // maximimum distance from start
        {
            // init record of visited nodes
            std::vector<int> visited(nodeCount());

            // init record of distance from start node
            std::vector<int> dist(nodeCount());

            // construct stack for nodes ready to be visited
            std::stack<int> stack;

            // add start node to stack
            stack.push(v);

            // while nodes waiting to be visited
            while (!stack.empty())
            {
                // pull next node from stack
                int v = stack.top();
                stack.pop();

                // mark node visited
                visited[v] = 1;

                // check if we need to go deeper
                if (dist[v] < maxdepth)
                {
                    // iterate over adjacent nodes
                    for (int w : adjacent(v))
                    {
                        // check adjacent not visited
                        if (!visited[w])
                        {
                            // store distance from start node
                            dist[w] = dist[v] + 1;

                            // add to stack of nodes to be visited
                            stack.push(w);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // count nodes within maxdepth of start nodes
            int countClose = 0;
            for (int d : dist)
            {
                if (d > 0 && d <= maxdepth)
                    countClose++;
            }
            return countClose;
        }
```

For this graph

```
finder.addLink("0", "2");
finder.addLink("0", "1");
finder.addLink("1", "12");
finder.addLink("12", "13");
finder.addLink("13", "14");
```

the output is

```
count by 2 is 3
```

Code for the entire application at https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder3